# clicking should reveal the rest of the text

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to angular and I have a p tag with a list of paragraphs and data(nested array of objects) for p tag will be coming from the backend. I need to truncate the text after some character limit and show`....show more`. when a user clicks on the p tag it should show reveal the rest of the text. I have figure out the way to truncate the text and display `...show more`.clicking should reveal that specific paragraph text but in my case, all other paragraphs texts which are truncated are also showing full texts and since the data is nested array of objects it is tricky for me and i am not able to figure out the solution. I am providing the stackblitz link below. any help will be appreciated.

[stackblitz link](https://angular-ivy-eueya8.stackblitz.io)

```js
data = [
        {
      comments:[
        {text:'this is comment',id:'1'},
         {text:'this is comment',id:'2'}
      ]
    },
            {
      comments:[
        {text:'this is comment',id:'3'},
         {text:'this is comment',id:'4'}
      ]
    },
            {
      comments:[
        {text:'this is comment',id:'5'},
         {text:'this is comment',id:'6'}
      ]
    }
  ]

 showrest:boolean = false
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let c of data">
  <div *ngFor="let comment of c['comments']">
    <p (click)="showrest=true">{{showrest?comment.text:(comment.text | slice:0:10)+'...Click to Read More'}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you could do, see this [repro on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-p2nolb/?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomment%2Fcomment.component.ts). You need a context for each comment so just create a component for it. Here is the code :

ts:

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-comment",
  templateUrl: "./comment.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./comment.component.css"]
})
export class CommentComponent {
  @Input() comment;
  showrest = false;
}
```

html:

```
<p (click)="showrest=!showrest">{{showrest?comment.text:(comment.text | slice:0:10)+'...Click to Read More'}}</p>
```

and you call it as follow :

app.html

```
<div *ngFor="let c of data">
    <div *ngFor="let comment of c['comments']">
        <app-comment [comment]="comment"></app-comment>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your problem was that each of your comment were bound to the same variable (Of the same component), so when yu click on a paragraph it update your variable and therefore all the binded element (here your paragraphs).

Another solution could be to add a property to your comment model, something like :

```
{text:'this is comment',id:'1', isFullyVisible: false},
```

This way your could handle the display of your comment with this variable. The best solution depends on what you intend to do with your comment. If it's just a display and nothing else then just adding a property to your model is good enough.